# How can i add spring mail api to my project

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I am getting below error. org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl is already defined in lib folder. Is spring using javax.mail? Do I need to also add the javax.mail library to my lib folder?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
```

My bean;

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download `javax.mail.jar` and add it to your classpath.